# Proxying Vaadin Spring Boot application and URL issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I've asked the [same question](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17220908/proxying-vaadin-spring-boot-application-and-url-problem) at Vaadin's forum, but noone responds there, so maybe someone here can help.

I've developed a Vaadin Spring Boot app that works perfectly when I run it as is, but when I tried to run it behind Apache Proxy (so that requests to http://website/vaadin-app/ are forwarded to http://website:8080), I've got a problem: UI is rendered successfully, but the data can't be fetched from the server. The error is: `The requested URL /vaadinServlet/UIDL/ was not found on this server`.

It looks like Vaadin doesn't make relative requests, but rather absolute ones, so it tries to load http://website/vaadinServlet/UIDL/ instead of http://website/vaadin-app/vaadinServlet/UIDL/

What kind of configuration should I add to address this issue?

Comment: Have you tried configuration help from the previous forum discussions: 
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/692065

and this (Cookie path is important to remember)

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/3620992

Comment: This is exactly how we worked it around at the moment. But it's just a work-around and not a real solution since we are adding some additional and unnecessary configuration to the Apache's setup. And what we want to achieve is to configure Vaadin and/or Spring somehow so it sends requests to corrects paths (relative ones).